# R plot frequency of strings with specific pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency-analysis

Given a data frame with a column that contains strings. I would like to plot the frequency of strings that bear a certain pattern. For example

```
strings  <- c("abcd","defd","hfjfjcd","kgjgcdjrye","yryriiir","twtettecd")
df <- as.data.frame(strings)
df
     strings
1       abcd
2       defd
3    hfjfjcd
4 kgjgcdjrye
5   yryriiir
6  twtettec
```

I would like to plot the frequency of the strings that contain the pattern `"cd"
Anyone with a quick solution?

Comment: All those strings are different. Do you just want TRUE/FALSE? ?grepl

Comment: What do you mean by plot the frequency? You can get the number with that pattern with `sum(grepl("cd",strings))`

Comment: Yes the strings are different but note that string 1,3 and 4 contain the "cd" pattern. What i need is an plot or a transformation that would allow one to plot the frequency of the strings containing "cd"

Comment: What do you imagine this plot looking like? 4/6 have cd, so how you think this should be plotted?

Comment: Hey James! Seems that is what i wanted! am good to go now!! Need to look more at the grepl command! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I presume from your question that you meant to have some entries that appear more than once, so I've added one duplicate string:

```
x <- c("abcd","abcd","defd","hfjfjcd","kgjgcdjrye","yryriiir","twtettecd")
```

To find only those strings that contain a specific pattern, use `grep` or `grepl`:

```
y <- x[grepl("cd", x)]
```

To get a table of frequencies, you can use `table`

```
table(y)

y
      abcd    hfjfjcd kgjgcdjrye  twtettecd 
         2          1          1          1
```

And you can plot it using `plot` or `barplot` as follows:

```
barplot(table(y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip and approach. I needed the numbers. The strings are rather long and plotting it using this approach is rather not very visually appealing. Will get totals and rename them and produce the desired plot! Thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned grepl. Here is an implementation with plot.density using grep to get the positions of the matches[image]

```
plot( density(0+grepl("cd", strings)) )
```

If you don't like the extension of the density plot beyond the range there are other methods in the 'logspline' package that allow one to get sharp border at range extremes. Searching RSiteSearch

Answer (score 1):

check ["Kernlab"](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDAQFjAD&url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringkernels/stringkernels.pdf&ei=98EHToSZAtDKswagvIjSDA&usg=AFQjCNFwGRUpXzXCMdqOrEbe9o5piEyn0w) package. 
You can define a kernel (pattern) which could any kind of string and count them later on.